# Cant install GIMP on elementary os

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt, gimp, elementary-os

After last update my gimp dissapeared. When im trying to install it, i got the message:

```
sudo apt install gimp      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.8.22-z) but 2.9.7~17-ubu16.04.1~ppa~9eb75cd is to be installed
        Depends: gimp-data (<= 2.8.22-z) but 2.9.7~17-ubu16.04.1~ppa~9eb75cd is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I reapre it?

Comment: You have obviously a mix of the "official" gimp 2.8.x and the WIP 2.9.x version possibly via the gimp-edge PPA. I would suggest to remove the PPA from the software sources, uninstall Gimp, add the PPA again to the software sources back and install. Another solution is to install Gimp 2.8 and use an AppImage for Gimp 2.9: see [here](https://discuss.pixls.us/t/community-built-software/2137).

Comment: thanks, thats resolves my problem :)